# syntax search of a string within a column

Tags: excel, vba

Thinking about this , I might need some VBA but if I can avoid it, it would be great.

I have the following excel sheet (see picture)

[image]

Aim : I want to put in column B the results of a syntaxic search on column C done with column A. In my case, column B will be `yes,tata,well` as column A has I2010 etc.

I've tried with a `vlookup` but `vlookup` is aiming for the specific string e.g `I2010`or `IS-IPI` not part of them.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need VBA for this since it requires iteration over *multiple* conditions.

Comment: Thanks David. Ouin ouin ouin ...

Comment: Not sure I understand. I don't see "RT" in that string in A1. Am I missing something?

Comment: I made a mistake. I've amended my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usage

```
andylookup(A1, C1:D4, "Not Found!")
```

Code:

```
Function andyLookup(strInput As String, rngTable As Range, defaultvalue As String) As String
    Dim strArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim temp1 As Variant

    strArray = Split(strInput, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(strArray)

        temp1 = Application.VLookup(strArray(i), rngTable, 2, 0)
        'if not found, apply default value
        If IsError(temp1) Then
        strOut = strOut & defaultvalue & ","
        Else
        strOut = strOut & temp1 & ","
        End If

    Next

    'remove trailing comma
    strOut = Left(strOut, Len(strOut) - 1)
    andyLookup = strOut

End Function
```

result

```
yes,toto,tata,well
```

Comment: Works like a tread Danny. However, can you explain a bit , please? I'm new to the vba brave world.

Comment: Yes but can you explain a bit , please?

Comment: strArray = Split(strInput, ",") - will split the string "a,b,c,d" into an array of 4 elements where array(0) = "a", array(1) = "b", array(2) = "c", etc.

I am looping thru the array, and lookup the value one by one: if found, append it to the output string, else, append the argument:defaultvalue as the string to the output

Answer (score 0):

In B1, type:

```
 =IF(FIND(C1,$A$1)>0,D1,"")
```

Then drag down. This will change depending on exactly what you want to do in your sheet. More clarification would be needed to tailor it more towards your needs, but this gives you a starting point at least.

Comment: Thanks @asp8811. It could do the trick with a transpose and a column fusion concatenated with a comma. Mmmhh...

Answer (score 0):

Or using VBA's `Find`

```
Sub Main()
MsgBox LookupStr(Range("A1"), Range("B1:B4"))
End Sub

Function LookupStr(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As String
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim rng4 As Range
For Each rng3 In rng2
Set rng4 = rng1.Find(rng3.Value, , xlFormulas, xlPart)
If Not rng4 Is Nothing Then LookupStr = LookupStr & rng3.Offset(0, 1) & vbNewLine
Next
End Function
```